# How complete records in onMutation with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am updating records from copied set with prefetchQuery and after updating iam shifting array, but I need the actual set when the array is null. How to start prefetchQuery in onMutation ?

this is how it looks like https://youtu.be/ULXUIHTsiP4

this is where i push next actual record in place of deleted to keep the same number of records on the page with nextPage?.data.shift();

```
import { Set, DataAny } from "../../../../model/Interface";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { len } from "./useGetSortedData";
let len1 = len;
export const useDeleteRow = (set: Set, currentPage: number) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const mutator = useMutation(
    async (id1: number) => {
      let r;
      try {
        r = await fetch(
          set.host + set.database + "/" + set.actcategory + "/remove/" + id1,
          {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
        return await r.json();
      } catch (error) {
        alert("dd " + error);
      }
    },
    {
      onMutate: async (id1) => {
        // cancel all queries that contain the key "issues"
        await queryClient.cancelQueries(["paginate", "sort"]);

        const currentPage1: any = (
          queryClient.getQueryData(["paginate", currentPage]) as DataAny
        )["data"];
        const nextPage: any =
          (queryClient.getQueryData([
            "paginate",
            Number(currentPage) + 1,
          ]) as DataAny) &&
          (
            queryClient.getQueryData([
              "paginate",
              Number(currentPage) + 1,
            ]) as DataAny
          )["data"];

        (currentPage1 as DataAny) &&
          (currentPage1 as DataAny)["data"].splice(
            (currentPage1 as DataAny) &&
              (currentPage1 as DataAny)["data"].findIndex((t) => {
                return t.id === id1 && t;
              }),
            1
          ); // eslint-disable-next-line

        // there might not be any issues left to add if a user clicks fast
        // and/or the internet connection is slow

        // remove resolved issue from the cache so it immediately
        // disappears from the UI

        /*       queryClient.setQueryData(["issues"], {
            ...currentPage,
            items: currentPage.items.filter(({ id }) => id !== issueId),
          });
  */

        //alert(JSON.stringify(currentPage1));
        if (currentPage1 && currentPage1["data"]) {
          queryClient.setQueryData(["paginate", id1], {
            ...currentPage1,
            data: {
              data: currentPage1.data.push(nextPage.data[0]),
            },
          });
        }
        nextPage?.data.shift();
        console.log(
          "oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo",
          JSON.stringify(nextPage)
        );

        // save the current data in the mutation context to be able to
        // restore the previous state in case of an error

        len1 = currentPage1.obj[set.actcategory];
        return { currentPage1, nextPage };
      },
      onSettled: async (res) => {
        // flag the query with key ["issues"] as invalidated
        // this causes a refetch of the issues data
        len1 = res.obj[set.actcategory];
      },
      onSuccess: async () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["paginate", 5]);
      },
    }
  );
  return { mutator, len1 };
};
```

and that how look like my prefetchquery

```
import { Set } from "../../../../model/Interface";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getRec } from "../../../../utils/rest";

const useGetPaginatedData = (
  changeLocation: string,
  pageSize: number,
  direction: boolean,
  len: number,
  currentPage: number,
  set: Set,
  actcategory: string
) => {
  let { data, isFetching, isLoading, isSuccess, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["paginate", currentPage, changeLocation],
    async () => {
      let url: string =
        set &&
        set.host +
          set.database +
          "/paginate/" +
          actcategory +
          "/" +
          currentPage +
          "/" +
          pageSize;

      // console.log("paginate 1");

      return getRec(url);
    },
    { keepPreviousData: true, staleTime: 10000 }
  );
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  useEffect(() => {
    const f = async () => {
      let url: string =
        set &&
        set.host +
          set.database +
          "/paginate/" +
          actcategory +
          "/" +
          currentPage +
          "/" +
          pageSize;

      // console.log("paginate 1");

      return getRec(url);
    };
    f(); // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    let url: string =
      set &&
      set.host +
        set.database +
        "/paginate/" +
        actcategory +
        "/" +
        currentPage +
        "/" +
        pageSize;
    queryClient.prefetchQuery(["paginate", currentPage], async () => {
      //console.log("prefetch 1");
      return getRec(url);
    });
    let url1: string =
      set &&
      set.host +
        set.database +
        "/paginate/" +
        actcategory +
        "/" +
        (Number(currentPage) + 1) +
        "/" +
        pageSize;
    queryClient.prefetchQuery(
      ["paginate", Number(currentPage) + 1],
      async () => {
        console.log("prefetch 1+1");
        return getRec(url1);
      }
    );

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [currentPage, queryClient]);

  return { isLoading, isFetching, isSuccess, data, refetch } as const;
};
```